# problem with function which not continue in next while

Tags: php, mysql

Search.php

```
function Search() {
    $db = $this->database[GDB];
    $character = trim($this->site->SanitizeName(@$_GET['char']));

    $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT * FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId LIKE \'%' . $character . '%\'');
    if (0 > $num_rows) {
        $this->content = Template::Load('error', array('errmsg' => $db->getError()));
        return;
    }
    if(empty(@$_GET['char']))
    {
        $this->content = Template::Load('error', array('errmsg' => 'You must enter a character name. '));
        return;
    }
    $nations[1] = 'Karus';
    $nations[2] = 'El Morad';

    $races['Karus'] = array(1 => 'Arch Tuarek', 2 => 'Tuarek', 3 => 'Wrinkle Tuarek', 4 => 'Puri Tuarek');
    $races['El Morad'] = array(11 => 'Berserker', 12 => 'El Morad Male', 13 => 'El Morad Female');

    $classes['Karus'] = array(101 => 'Warrior', 102 => 'Rogue', 103 => 'Magician', 104 => 'Priest', 105 => 'Berserker', 106 => 'Berserker Hero', 107 => 'Hunter', 108 => 'Shadow Vain', 109 => 'Sorcerer', 110 => 'Elemental Lord', 111 => 'Shaman', 112 => 'Shadow Knight');
    $classes['El Morad'] = array(201 => 'Warrior', 202 => 'Rogue', 203 => 'Magician', 204 => 'Priest', 205 => 'Blade', 206 => 'Blade Master', 207 => 'Ranger', 208 => 'Kasar Hood', 209 => 'Mage', 210 => 'Arch Mage', 211 => 'Cleric', 212 => 'Paladin');
    $chars = '';

    $content = '';
    while($row = $db->doRead()) {
    $race = isset($races[$nations[$row['Nation']]][$row['Race']]) ? $races[$nations[$row['Nation']]][$row['Race']] : 'unknown';
    $class = isset($classes[$nations[$row['Nation']]][$row['Class']]) ? $classes[$nations[$row['Nation']]][$row['Class']] : 'unknown';

        $nick =  $row['strUserId'];
    $content .= Template::Load('search_users', array(
    'nick' => $nick,
    'nation' => $nations[$row['Nation']],
    'race' => $race,
    'class' => $class,
    'country' => $this->site->GetAccountCountry($nick),
    'level' => $row['Level'],
    'loyalty' => $row['Loyalty'])
    );
    }
    $this->content = Template::Load('search', array('search_show' => $content));
}
```

It is the function, This function work only one time, the next time it stop  after next SELECT...

```
function GetAccountCountry($user)
{
      $db = $this->database[GDB];
      $num_rows = $db->doQuery("select strAccountID from ACCOUNT_CHAR where strCharID1='$user' OR strCharID2='$user' OR strCharID3='$user'");
      if($num_rows = 0)
      {
                $this->content = Template::Load('error', array('errmsg' => 'ERR: FLAG'));
                return;
      }
      $row = $db->doRead();
      $account = $row['strAccountID'];

      $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Country FROM TB_USER WHERE strAccountID = ?', $account);
      if($num_rows = 0)
      {
                $this->content = Template::Load('error', array('errmsg' => 'ERR: FLAG'));
                return;
      }
      $row = $db->doRead();
      $country = $row['Country'];
      return $country;

}
```

Someone know why it happen? I try to get the Country for everyone user in search but it won't make second row in my result.
When i not using the function it is working normal, show my all search people. If i used only one row(one results)

Comment: Pleassse use error reporting. Also parameterize your queries.

Answer (score 1):

You talk about mysql. So I assume the bug is here:

```
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT * FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId LIKE \'%' . $character . '%\'');
if (0 > $num_rows) {
```

The if-line is incorrect. Usually the  result of the query is either `FALSE` on error or an result-object. But here I don't know the kind of object of `$db`. Anyway `if (0 > $num_rows)` looks very strange.`

Answer (score 0):

1. You're mixing the syntax of prepared statements with unprepared statements. Make your second statement more like the first statement (no `?`). That's why nothing is being returned for:

```php
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Country FROM TB_USER WHERE strAccountID = ?', $account);
```

2. Do not use unprepared statements, they are a security risk and your site can get hacked that way. Please really look into using prepared statements in your SQL queries.